# SQL Server : how can I make this delete query more efficient?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I need to run this query on my database, but it takes forever. I have over 1 000 000 records in the table. Is there a way to make it more efficient?

```
delete
from CON
where id in (select id
             from CON co
             where not exists (select id
                               from AC ac
                               where ac.ID = co.ID_)
            )
```

Comment: Which is more, the number of removals or the number of leftovers?

Comment: the number of removals is more.

Comment: Do you any Foreign Key constraints that reference CON?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query to delete items in CON which do not match with items in AC

```
delete co from 
CON co left join
Ac ac on ac.ID = co.ID_
where ac.ID is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You could skip the `in()` and just use `not exists()`.

```
delete
from con
where not exists (
    select 1
    from ac 
    where ac.id = con.id
    );
```

Unless there is something else going on that was removed when simplifying your example query.

Answer (score 0):

You want to keep your transactions small. Try deleting 10000 rows at a time like so:

```
delete TOP (10000)from CON
where id in (
  select id
  from CON co
  where not exists (
    select id
    from AC ac
    where ac.ID = co.ID_
    )
  )
WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0
    delete TOP (10000) from CON
where id in (
  select id
  from CON co
  where not exists (
    select id
    from AC ac
    where ac.ID = co.ID_
    )
  )
```

You can try experimenting with 1000 or 10000 rows at a time.